# Are these inner product spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-spaces

1) Vector space of $2\times2$ real matrices and $(A,B)=\text{trace}(AB)$

2) Vector space consisting of all polynomials of degree $2$ with $\langle p,q\rangle=p(-1)q(-1)+p(1/2)q(1/2)+p(-1)q(-1)$

How can I use the definition of an inner product space to justify these?

Comment: I'd start by writing out the definition of an inner product and checking each part.

Answer (score 1):

The inner product satisfies: ($u,v$ vectors, $A$ scalar)

i) $<u+v,w>=<u,w>+<v,w>$

ii) $<A v,w>=A<v,w>$

iii) $<v,w>=<w,v>$

iv) $<v,v>\geq0\mbox{ and equal to $0$ iff }v=0$

Defining $<A,B>=\operatorname{trace}(AB)$ and letting $C$ be some other $2\times 2$ matrix gives:

i) $<A+C,B>=\operatorname{trace}((A+C)B)=\operatorname{trace}(AB)+\operatorname{trace}(CB)$

ii) $<x A,B>=\operatorname{trace}(xAB)=x\operatorname{trace}(AB)=x<A,B>$

iii) $<A,B>=\operatorname{trace}(AB)=\operatorname{trace}(BA)=<B,A>$

iv) $<A,A>=\operatorname{trace}(A^2)\geq0\mbox{ and equal to $0$ iff }A=0$

You can check for 2).

Comment: the first does not satisfy property iv), correct?

Comment: Yes - the first does not satisfy property iv).